Do pureed tomatoes loose any flavour or compounds etc compared to whole tomatoes?
I’m currently using the jar of uk whole fruit tomato pasata(whole fruit puree In America) In the picture attached.
On their producers website it says the tomatoes are organic, use no additives and ‘takes less than 24 hours from vine to jar, a speedy process’.  Of course they will then be on the shelf for a bit of time.
My question is, from the point of being pureed/crushed and to me using them, are there any changes in flavour or compounds compared to a whole tomato.
Now obviously you won’t get the flavours of tasting the skin, crushing with your teeth etc but I’m not asking about that, I’m asking I’m other senses as would happen if you grounded herbs and spices and they were put in a jar etc we know the oxidation leads to degradation over time.  I would say yes since, I don’t know how to describe it but this product tastes less vibrant compared to fresh tomatoes.  But I notice the product is a very dark red and not bright red so could be a difference in tomatoes perhaps?
Do crushed and jarred tomatoes degrade in any way or loose flavour, experience any other changes etc as a result of being crushed and jarred until you open the jar lid?
Thanks

Worth noting that if you're in the UK, tomatoes are very out of season and will have very little taste; good canned tomatoes are produced at the height of the season and will have much more flavour.
